# If NULL pass blank instead

Tags: sql

I need to push data from a SQL table to an intermediate table in JDE. I am having issues with NULLS not being passed as blanks. How can I replace any NULL values with blanks into JDE.

This is my statement to update my SQLDB:

```
Insert into AP_InvoiceHeader
(DocID,[Vendor Name],[Vendor No],[Invoice Number],[Invoice Date],[PO Number],[Invoice Amount],MVRUploadDate,DocName)

values ({sys DocID},'{doc Vendor Name}','{doc Vendor No}','{doc Invoice Number}','{doc Invoice Date}','{doc PO Number}','{doc Invoice Amount}',GETDATE(),(select DocName from document where Docid={sys DocID}))
```

With this statement, if there isn't a value to pass, it shows up as NULL in SQL. Would it be better to do a NULL to blank conversion into my SQLDB or should it be done when I update the intermediate table?

This is my statement that selects from my SQLDB and inserts it into the intermediate JDE table. I know what I want to do but, I am not sure how to write it. I would like to say, if `[PO Number]=NULL` change it to blank. Is there a way that it can check for any NULLS and replace all NULLS with blanks?

```
 INSERT INTO [MyJDE_VENDOR].[PS_DEV].[TESTDTA].[F55METAA] ([MVMLNM],[MVAN8],[MVVR01],[MVVINV],[MVDIVJ],[MVAG],[MVTRDJ],[MVRMK3],[MV55MV],[MVUMEMO1])

    SELECT [Vendor Name],[Vendor No],[PO Number],[Invoice Number],cast('1'+ RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(cast([Invoice Date] as date)) AS CHAR(4)),2) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(DATEPART(dy, cast([Invoice Date] as date)) AS varchar(3)),3) as int) as [Invoice Date],[Invoice Amount]*100,cast('1'+ RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(cast([MVRUploadDate] as date)) AS CHAR(4)),2) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(DATEPART(dy, cast([MVRUploadDate] as date)) AS varchar(3)),3) as int) as [MVRUploadDate],[ProcessedFlag],[DocID],[DocName]

    FROM [MyDataBase].[dbo].[AP_InvoiceHeader] WHERE DocID ={sys DocID}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `COALESCE`...  Other options as well depending on the specific RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

The standard SQL function is `coalesce()`.  It is a bit unclear which fields you want this for:

```
INSERT INTO [MyJDE_VENDOR].[PS_DEV].[TESTDTA].[F55METAA] ([MVMLNM],[MVAN8],[MVVR01],[MVVINV],[MVDIVJ],[MVAG],[MVTRDJ],[MVRMK3],[MV55MV],[MVUMEMO1])

SELECT coalesce([Vendor Name], ''),
       coalesce([Vendor No], ''), 
       coalesce([PO Number], ''),
       coalesce([Invoice Number], '')
       coalesce(cast('1'+ RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(cast([Invoice Date] as date)) AS CHAR(4)),2) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(DATEPART(dy, cast([Invoice Date] as date)) AS varchar(3)),3) as int) as [Invoice Date],[Invoice Amount]*100,cast('1'+ RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(cast([MVRUploadDate] as date)) AS CHAR(4)),2) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(DATEPART(dy, cast([MVRUploadDate] as date)) AS varchar(3)),3) as int) , '') as [MVRUploadDate],
       coalesce([ProcessedFlag], ''), 
       coalesce([DocID], ''), 
       coalesce([DocName], '')
FROM [MyDataBase].[dbo].[AP_InvoiceHeader]
WHERE DocID ={sys DocID}
```

Comment: I would want this for all fields, in case the invoice doesn't have a PO Number or Vendor Name. I will edit coalesce9[Invoice Number], '') to coalesce([Invoice Number], '') and try it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL SERVER, if you are specifically targeting nulls then you can use the isnull function.

```
isnull(column,'')
```

Comment: is there a way to use that against the whole statement?




SELECT
[Vendor Name],
[Vendor No],
[PO Number],
[Invoice Number],
cast('1'+ RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(cast([Invoice Date] as date)) AS CHAR(4)),2) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(DATEPART(dy, cast([Invoice Date] as date)) AS varchar(3)),3) as int) as [Invoice Date],
[Invoice Amount]*100,
cast('1'+ RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(cast([MVRUploadDate] as date)) AS CHAR(4)),2) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(DATEPART(dy, cast([MVRUploadDate] as date)) AS varchar(3)),3) as int) as [MVRUploadDate],
[ProcessedFlag],
[DocID],
[DocName]

Comment: as far as i know, you have to do it on each column. it looks like you are converting all the columns to strings so at this point all you have to do is put the columns in the isnull function: `code`ISNULL (cast('1'+ RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(cast([Invoice Date] as date)) AS CHAR(4)),2) + RIGHT('000' + CAST(DATEPART(dy, cast([Invoice Date] as date)) AS varchar(3)),3) as int),'') as [Invoice Date]`code`. Standard practice is to show blanks in the application and keep the nulls in the database.